# Can't Remember Auth Session in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to `Auth` Attempt for login in Laravel. and Successfully Logged . But can't Remember `Auth` Session.

My `kernel.php` file :

```
<?php

     namespace App\Http;

     use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

     class Kernel extends HttpKernel
     {
        /**
       * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

}

Auth.php file is:

```
<?php
```

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

];

```
HomeController.php Code is :

 public function login(Request $request){        
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->all(); 
        $any = array('email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']);
        if(auth()->attempt($any)){
            dd("logged"); //This code is running when i try to login
                          //but after when i try to get Auth::check() then it return false
        }
    }
}
```

My web.php File :

```
<?php
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'],function(){
        Route::match(['get','post'],'/', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::match(['get','post'],'/login', 'HomeController@login');
        Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){    
      });
   });
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Pretty sure you don't need `['middleware'=>'web']` where you have it; that's applied to all routes in `web.php` by default.

Comment: Thanks for answer . But i remove [link] ['middleware'=>'web'] but it still not working. When i try Auth attempt then it destroy all session which i need to use. I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: Why not use `Auth::attempt($any)`?

Comment: @vivek_23 That's same thing , I tried it but same result . I don't know why destroy all session when  `Auth::attempt($any)` or `auth()->attempt($any)`.

Comment: @RajKumar that is weird. Have you changed anything in framework or is this a fresh laravel application you are working on?

Comment: @vivek_23 no, i already completed 5 project in laravel. Yes i am using fresh laravel application . I am using latest laravel 5.6 version and before i used 5.4 and 5.4 version is also giving same result.

Comment: can you please stop making methods that return views and process data ... that is why you have routes and methods so you dont have to do the old PHP script way of shoving everything into one script

Comment: @lagbox Thanks sir for answer. But i solved problem. Ok sir i will not return any views. Thanks again (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Let's check my HomeController code

```
public function login(Request $request){        
if($request->isMethod('post')){
    $data = $request->all(); 
    $any = array('email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']);
    if(auth()->attempt($any)){
        dd("logged"); //This code is running when i try to login
                      //but after when i try to get Auth::check() then it return false
    }
}
```

}

when auth attempt is successful then i stop code with `dd("Logged");` if i stopped code then the auth attempt is not full completed. I removed `dd("Logged");` then i make redirect to dashboard.

```
        if(auth()->attempt($any)){
           return Redirect('/dashboard');
        }
```

Then i check auth with `Auth::check()` and it return `true` . Thanks Guys for Posting Your Valuable Comments and Answers . I really Appreciate it.

Comment: ok, dd() stops the script as well. So, if you add a Auth::check() after it, it won't run anyway. Also, actually redirect isn't the solution. You can just add only  `var_dump(Auth::check())` inside the condition and I am pretty sure it will give you the right results.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks Vivek. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to Authenticate users by calling so:

```
Auth::attempt($user_credentails);
```

instead of auth()

Comment: Why you don't use default route for login?

Comment: because i never used default route login in any my laravel project. My previous laravel projects working fine but this one not.